# Where should we store confirmation/error messages in application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, messaging

I am working on PHP and Zend. I have to show different type of error/confirmation messages in application. Most of these messages are placed in code. So if I have to change one message then I have to change it everywhere where this particular type of message is coded.

So what is the best way to store all messages in on place and use them across the application.

**Possible solutions:**

- Store all messages in database. *(We have to move these messages to other database type. For example if we move from MySQL to SQL Server.)*
- Store all messages in separate php class using array and get these messages using class methods *(Problem: We can not use this class in other programming languages.)*
- Store message in special format which acceptable for all languages for example ini type of files.

**EDIT:** *(After looking Ozair's [Answer](http://After%20seeing%20Ozair%27s%20Answer))*

Sometimes we have to change message for particular record. For example:

```
Product No. 10 is deleted.
Product No. 15 is deleted.
```

What will be best method to handle this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have some sort of static class in the library folder. Which would contain a set of constant variables like

```
PRODUCT_SAVED_OK = "The product {{id}} was saved successfully";
```

The I would have two static methods which take care of displaying the error/message

```
public static function showMessage($message , $data = array("id" => "10"){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $message = str_replace("{{" . $key . "}}", $value , $message);
    }
    echo $message;
}

public static function showError($error){
   echo $error;
}
```

Than in your code whenever you need to display the message you simply invoke the static class like so...

```
Messages::showMessage(Messages::PRODUCT_SAVED_OK);
```

That way all the messages the application needs will be contained in one class and if need be that the message changes you only have to change it this class.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you can take a simpler approach than what Ozair suggested. I changed the code in my answer to show you how. Basically the constant variables would have placeholders for the dynamic information. Simple pass the data in  the array format as indicated in the code. The foreach loop will take care of put the data you passed in the message.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to go and look at is what your problem is.

For you it seems like code maintenance. What I have found to work is storing all these messages as a separate class for example called `Notifications` (just an example though)

Every type of notification you would call can be stored as a method so when you call the notifier it would get some message from class members which can easily be changed according to your needs.

Storing these messages in a database is not a bad way of doing it, just not the real solution to your need at this point. That means having to maintain another table adding extra queries to your code which have to be escaped properly etc. In short, more maintenance instead of less.

I would go for the class in which you can store these messages as class constants.

Also, members of this class can very easily be translated so it would be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing it in some non-direct coding language and then use a macro for transforming this into an array or static class or whatever you like? It may be in the database, XML or whatever you'd like. You would only need 2 fields for an error message: the name of the message and the content.

For example, in XML you might do this:

```
<messages>
  <message>
    <name>PRODUCT_SAVED_OK</name>
    <content>Product no. %d has been saved successfully</content>
  </message>
  ...
</messages>
```

Then have some process to transform this into arrays or the thing that best fits your project. For example, I would save this to an array:

```
$messages = array(
  'PRODUCT_SAVED_OK' => 'Product no. %d has been saved successfully',
  ...
);
```

And for dealing with variables inside the messages, I'd do `printf`s:

```
if ($saved_ok)
{
  printf($messages['PRODUCT_SAVED_OK'], $product_number);
}
```

Of course, encapsulate this inside a Message class for better and cleaner code. One drawback of the `printf` solution is that you need to know in advance which parameters do any message need. If you'd like to translate the message and some message with more than one parameter gets them inverted in another language, `printf` can deal with this:

```
// In both cases, day would be 3rd parameter to printf, month the second and year the first
$spanish = 'Hoy es %3$d/%2$d/%1$d';
$english = 'Today is %2$d/%3$d/%1$d';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only static messages, [ElGabbu's unedited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6184151/1) will suffice.

However, if you want to display messages like:

> The product *product name* has been
>   saved successfully.

You will need more than that. In that case you should define a `Message` class as follows:

```
class Message {

    public getMessage() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Then for product saved message, you need a subclass

```
class ProductSaved extends Message {

    private $productName_ = "";

    __contruct($productName) {

        $this->productName_ = $productName;

    }

    public getMessage() {

        return "The product $productName_ has been saved successfully.";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be using Zend_Translate (even if you don't have multilanguage version of your website) + .ini file, .ini can be accepted by other applications/languages and you can read it directly in translator or through Zend_Config_Ini. You can use xml file in the same way. Huge pro is that you can easily connect Zend_Translator with Zend_Form and have translated labels and validation errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

"I used Zend Framework's Translator to store form validation message strings in ini files:

Module.php

```
use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;


class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        ....

        $translatorInterface =  new TranslatorInterface();

        $translatorInterface->addTranslationFile( 'ini', dirname(__FILE__ ) . '/language/en_UK.ini' );

        $translator =  new Translator( $translatorInterface );

        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

Then in ./module/MyModule/language/en_UK.ini

```
[tag_approved_but_no_id]
message     = tag_approved_but_no_id
translation = "You have entered 'Yes' but not entered a tag ID must be entered"

[tag_unapproved_but_no_reason]
message     = tag_unapproved_but_no_reason
translation = "You have entered 'No' but not entered a reason"
```

Then in the form:

```
    $inputFilter->add( array(
        'name'     => 'hasTagApproval',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Callback',
                'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'tag_approved_but_no_id',
                    ),

                    .....
                ),
            ),
```